# Google-maps-react not loading map

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

When I'm trying to load component with Google Maps, (props was passed to the component as expected), I'm just getting a message saying `"Loading map..."` but a map with markers was not loaded. No errors in the console as well. Here is the component. What I'm doing wrong here?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';
import { Constants } from './../../utils/constants';

export class MapContainer extends Component {

    state = {
        selectedPlace: ''
    }

    onMarkerClick = (e) => {
        this.setState({selectedPlace: e.Name});
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <Map 
        google={this.props.google}
        style={{width: '20vw', height: '45vh', 'top': '1.5rem'}}
        containerStyle={{width: '20vw', height: '30vh'}}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: this.props.lat,
          lng: this.props.lng
        }}
        zoom={15}>
        {this.props.markers.length > 0 && // Rendering multiple markers for 
          this.props.markers.map((m) => {
            return (<Marker 
                      onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                      name={this.state.selectedPlace}
                      position={{ lat: m.Latitude, lng: m.Longitude }}
                      key={m.Name} />);
          })
        }

        {this.props.markers && // Rendering single marker for supplier details map
          <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                name={this.state.selectedPlace} />
        }

        <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>
              <h4>{this.state.selectedPlace}</h4>
        </InfoWindow>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: (Constants.GoogleMapsApiKey),
  language: "RU"
})(MapContainer)
```

Comment: Can you post a codesandbox/stackblitz of your code?

Comment: By any chance, you have an adblocker? These can interfere with scripts and cause such issues

Comment: @TarunLalwani, no I don't have any kind of adblocker (but I should).

Comment: @MunimMunna, here is the link to the codesandbox (without API key of course) https://codesandbox.io/s/google-maps-react-t00do

Comment: Instead of `export default GoogleApiWrapper` use `App = GoogleApiWrapper` as you are using maps in your App component. You can (and should) move your map to a child component too.

Comment: @MunimMunna, not sure that I got your point, but look like it doesn't help as well.

Comment: @MunimMunna, please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your codesandbox demo, you are exporting your app component, where you need to render it.

```
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "",
  language: "RU"
})(App);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here you are rendering the app component which is not wrapped by `GoogleApiWrapper` HOC.
Instead of exporting the wrapped app, render it as follows:

```
App = GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "",
  language: "RU"
})(App);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting the width and height of the map in pixels

```
style={{width: '200px', height: '450px', 'top': '1.5rem'}}
```